# video js scrubber not working - reverts back to start

Tags: html, video-streaming, video.js

When I  mousedown on the scrubber, instead of allowing me to move to a different place in the video, it goes back to start everytime. I am using 2 types of video- one that uses a url - it works fine. The one that does not work is using a video that I am saving and redisplaying - could this be the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do don't say how you implemented "saved and redisplayed" video, but you need to support byte range requests so that when the browser requests the part of the video seeked to, that part is received and not the file from the start again. There are several questions here on that if you search for range requests and whthe language/framework you're using.